# How to select a file name (variable) once and use that same file name for each following execution without having to choose the file

Tags: excel, vba, file

I'm building a macro to open a constant named file but use a varying file name and tab name that the macro is run from.

I build the code originally to open one specific file name and one specific tab name but then realized as I saved the file as a different name that the code always went back to the original file not the new named file and the same issue once I started changing tab names. The whole macro will use the same file and tab to run each time, but the file name and tab name the macro is in is never the same. I've changed the first ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 formula to specify the file name and tab name and left the same for the following lines to try and better explain what I'm trying to execute.

```
Sub Costingnon1()
'
' Costing***** Macro
' Create Costing Sheet
'
'

    ChDir "\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop\Costing Template Test.xlsx"
    Sheets("Open Quote").Select
    Range("B3:C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[File Name That Varies]Tab Name That Varies'!R6C2"
    Range("B4:C4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[QFCS-071  Request for Quotation Test 1.xlsm]Quote Data 1'!R3C4"
    Range("B6:C6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "='[QFCS-071  Request for Quotation Test 1.xlsm]Quote Data 1'!R1C15"
```

I expect the file to open and execute each step without having to choose the file name and file tab for every cell. I've gotten it to prompt me to pick a file and tab but the macro is filling in over 50 cells when it's executed so it's not any faster than just manually transferring the data by hand.

Comment: You've said "The whole macro will use the *same file* and tab to run each time, but the *file name and tab name the macro is in is never the same*" (emphasis mine) - you have to pick either the file is the same or it's not, it can't be both

Comment: The file that is being used will be the same name for each line in the macro run. I.e. the file to run all 50 placement of data will be “Data Found Here”. However, the next time it’s run the file name might be “File Also Here” so I can’t use a static file name. As for the tab it won’t be the same name as the file it might be “Data Set 1” in The first file and “New Data” in the next file. I’m willing to choose the file name and sheet the first time but I don’t want to have to select it for every single placement of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim wb as Workbook, sht as worksheet, pth

Set sht = ActiveSheet
pth = "='[" & sht.parent.name & "]" & sht.Name & "'!"



'ChDir "\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop" 'not needed here...
set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop\Costing Template Test.xlsx")

With wb.Sheets("Open Quote")

    .Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R6C2"

    'etc etc

End with
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives a compile error: Invalid outside Procedure at Set Sht = ActiveSheet.
 
Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, pth
    
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    pth = "='[" & sht.Parent.Name & "]" & sht.Name & "'!"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\FS3\Users$\UsersName\Desktop\Costing Template Test.xlsx")
    
    With wb.Sheets("Open Quote")
    .Range("B3:C3").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R6C2"
    .Range("B4:C4").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R3C4"
    .Range("B6:C6").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R1C15"
    .Range("B7:C7").FormulaR1C1 = pth & "R5C7"
End With

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I forgot to ad the sub back to the top/bottom. Thank you!